# handling missing values inside a customized function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to apply a customized function over a dictionary of dataframes, where it exists the possibility that some cells are `np.nan`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data demo

data = {'dataframe_1':pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['John', 'Ashley'], 'col2': ['+10', '-1']}), 'dataframe_2':pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['Italy', 'Brazil', 'Japan'], 'col4': ['Milan', 'Rio do Jaineiro', 'Tokio'], 'percentage':[np.nan, '75%', '80%']})}

############ converting every cell to string ########

for key in data:
     data[key]=data[key].astype("string")

        
####### function that converts to percentage ########

# from string --> float 
# x == a string cell inside a df

def convert_to_percentage(x):
    
    # my trial to handle missing values
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return np.nan
    
    elif x.str.contains("%", regex= False).any(): 
        x = x.str.strip('%')
        x = x.astype(float) / 100
        return x
    
    else:
        pass
```

When applying the function the next error arises:

```
# applying the function
for key in data:
     data[key] = data[key].apply(lambda x: convert_to_percentage(x))
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Expected Output:

```
data['dataframe_2']

#   col3    col4                 percentage
#0  Italy   Milan               <NA>
#1  Brazil  Rio do Jaineiro      0.00
#2  Japan   Tokio                0.8
```

How can I handle `np.nan` inside `convert_to_percentage(x)`?
Is there any other simpler way to handle them?

Comment: Are you looking for [`pd.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) ?

Comment: Is the error in the `astype` line?  Show traceback!

Comment: Hey @hpaulj, just updated the question, the error arises when the function is applied over each key

Answer (score 0):

This is a more compact way of going about it:

```
data["dataframe_2"]["percentage"].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)/100
```